# OpenAI API gives random and nonsense responses

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

I am developing a Next.js app where users pick some ingredients and get a recipe idea which can be made with them. I am using OpenAI API for that but I couldn't find a way to optimize it. I want to get responses with the same quality as in chatGPT (or something close to it) but instead, it gives me random, incomplete and out-of-context responses. I tried to play with max tokens, temperature, role, model etc. but it didn't work. Here is an example:

This is a prompt and response on chatGPT:

***prompt:***
*Create a recipe made with potato, paprika, salmon and yogurt. First state the title, then the ingredients list and then step-by-step instructions.*

***response:***
*Title: Paprika-Spiced Salmon with Creamy Potato and Yogurt Mash*

*Ingredients:*

*For the Salmon:*
*- 2 salmon fillets*
*- 1 teaspoon paprika*
*- Salt and pepper to taste*
*- 2 tablespoons olive oil*

*For the Creamy Potato and Yogurt Mash:*
*- 4 medium-sized potatoes, peeled and cut into chunks*
*- 1/2 cup plain yogurt*
*- Salt and pepper to taste*

*Instructions:*

*For the Salmon:*

*1. Preheat your oven to 375°F (190°C).*

*2. So on....*

This result is exactly what I want.

And this is the result I get when I try the same prompt with the API :

```
{
  "prompt": "Please create a recipe made with potato, paprika, salmon and yogurt. First state the title, then the ingredients list and then step-by-step instructions.",
  "max_tokens": 200,
  "temperature": 0.3
}

response: 

{
    "id": "cmpl-88ReJXcbcT3zstFOQTStJDnG528en",
    "object": "text_completion",
    "created": 1697023599,
    "model": "davinci",
    "choices": [
        {
            "text": "\n\nEasy ☆ Cooked rice remake risotto\n\nI will remake the cooked rice deliciously. Since the ingredients are already included, it is delicious risotto with only eggs.\n\nTakoyaki style rice ball\n\nI love takoyaki, but it is troublesome to make, so it's a Takoyaki style rice ball. Because the color is also beautiful, it is also recommended for Hinamatsuri and lunch.\n\nRange easy! Omurice style\n\nAll the ingredients are fine about your choice. Washing is easy because it can be made without the need for cooking utensils.\n\nEasy lunch ♡ ♡ ♡ 炒 rice bowl\n\nTuna fried rice ♡ パ ラ ふ ふ ふ ふ ふ ふ ふ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ す ぐ\n\nSoymilk Japanese-style doria\n\nThis",
            "index": 0,
            "logprobs": null,
            "finish_reason": "length"
        }
    ],
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 33,
        "completion_tokens": 200,
        "total_tokens": 233
    }
}
```

Are the some specific properties to optimize the results with API? Or is it not possible to get chatGPT-quality results no matter what I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure on which GPT version and model you are calling, But I can help you out a bit if you were using GPT 4 or GPT 4-32K

So basically to improve the quality of the response there are some ways.

1. The obvious one is the give a better prompt, but your prompt looks pretty fine. But yeah, it can get some improvements.
2. Keeping "temperature" to 0 would be ideal in this case.
3. Adding a parameter "top_p" and setting it to 0.95 would help. Just add "top_p":0.95 under the temperature parameter.
4. I would suggest removing "max_tokens". I get that you would like to keep the cost in control, but keeping the max_tokens to 200 would be low and I recommend to increase it a bit. Atleast adjust max_tokens to the number of tokens in the response in ChatGPT.
5. Giving it Few-Shot approach would help greatly here, it helps GPT to get context here, which actually helped my project a lot, in terms of better results.
6. Lastly, please follow the best practices for the body of the api request, The body that we send for GPT-4 and GPT 4-32K differs vastly when compared to the body you had shown in the question. Please update it.

Hope this helps. Thanks.